# How to prevent list box from clearing unintentionally in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-applications, ado.net

Just making an somewhat complex ASP.NET page, and am having an issue with list and text boxes.  Everytime I click a button and execute server side C# script, it clears the listboxes that I previously populated automatically.  Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 0):

Your page is getting post back each time.

Hence it is clearing up the data.

Use `Page.IsPostBack` Property for checking postbacks and handle the unncessary postbacks in your page.

Refer following link for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Also refer this useful article:

http://dotnet.tekyt.info/?p=30